# Adding a variable to a string in clojure

Tags: clojure

Just teaching myself clojure and wondering around:

I am trying to create a function that takes an argument and adds it to a string. Being a newbie, i dont know if i am doing it right or wrong but it is not working. I want it to say "Hello, Ron !"

```
(fn 
 [x] 
 ((str "hello, " %1 " !") x) "Ron")
```

This might sound basic

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: % in this
>   context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0)

Comment: What does your REPL say?  That would tell you for sure.

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin yh i am doing that but i thought there was a special way of concatenating string just like java or javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%1` syntax is for use with anonymous function literals, like this:

```
#(str "hello, " %1)
```

In your case, the argument is named, so you can use it directly:

```
(fn [x] (str "hello, " x "!"))
```

You can also name the function itself:

```
(defn hello [name] (str "hello, " name "!"))
```

Comment: perfectly fine. Thanks

Comment: The code isn't quite right. The latter two examples are better  `((fn [x] (str "hello, " x " !")) "Ron")` and `(defn hello [x] (str "hello, " x " !"))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a:

1. named function

`(defn hello [name] (str "hello, " name " !"))
 (hello "Ron")`

2. anonymous function

`((fn [name] (str "hello, " name " !")) "Ron")`

http://clojure.org/functional_programming